# Have a function as a property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I have a page containing a list of elements -clickable settings-, each of which have a SettingViewModel associated.
Each element is set in the constructor of the page view model, like so:

```
AccountSettingsVMList.Add(new SettingViewModel()
        {
            SettingTitle = AppResources.MainApp_EditProfileSetting,
            PageType = typeof(EditProfilePage)
        });
```

By clicking each element, I trigger the page navigation:

```
public void SelectSetting(SettingViewModel setting)
    {
        Type pageType = setting.PageType;
        if (pageType != null)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateToView(pageType);
        }
    }
```

Now, this all works fine and dandy, but for some settings I'd need to send serialized params. The problem is that I'd take these params by performing a webservice call, which is async.
I would need to know how to add a method pointer as a parameter to the ViewModel, so I can build the setting as:

```
AccountSettingsVMList.Add(new SettingViewModel()
        {
            SettingTitle = AppResources.MainApp_EditProfileSetting,
            PageType = typeof(EditProfilePage),
            Call = ProfileParams_Call
        });
```

and then, call that to get the parameter before navigating towards the view:

```
public void SelectSetting(SettingViewModel setting)
    {
        object obj = null;
        if (Call != null) 
        {
            obj = await Call();
        }

        Type pageType = setting.PageType;
        if (pageType != null)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateToView(pageType, obj);
        }
    }
```

How would you define the property inside SettingViewModel, to achieve this?

P.S: for completeness sake, this is currently the code for SettingViewModel:

```
public class SettingViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _settingTitle;

    public string SettingTitle
    {
        get { return _settingTitle; }
        set 
        {
            _settingTitle = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SettingTitle");
        }
    }

    private Type _settingPage;

    public Type PageType
    {
        get { return _settingPage; }
        set { _settingPage = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ProfileParams_Call` is the same in every case, then just use the built in delegate type `Func<T>` to hold a function that returns type T. Since the call is async, it will return a `Task<T>`.

Example. If `ProfileParams_Call` returns an object, and takes no arguments it would be:

```
public Func<Task<object>> Call { get; set; }
```

if each call has a different signature, then you'll need to wrap the call in a lambda or anonymous delegate that provides the arguments required.

eg

```
AccountSettingsVMList.Add(new SettingViewModel()
{
    SettingTitle = AppResources.MainApp_EditProfileSetting,
    PageType = typeof(EditProfilePage),
    Call = async () => await ProfileParams_Call(someArgument); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can create a property of type `Action<T>`. This property you can assign with a method having same type of parameter.